# How to get information on 200k emails in an IN Statement without receiving an error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get information for more than 150k emails that appear in different tables.

My query looks like:

```
   ;with emails as (
       select distinct m.email, m.id
       from databasename.list as m
       where m.email in 
            (
            list of 150k emails
             )
```

Then I'm using basic select statements to gather all the information I need.

```
select m.email
    ,m.id
    ,poe.order_time
    ,poe.order_id
    ,poi.price
from emails as m
left join database.purchase_order_entry as poe
on m.id=poe.member_id
left join database.purchase_order_item as poi
on poe.order_id=poi.order_id
where 1=1
    and poe.order_time > '2018-11-02'
```

I get the following error message:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

How can I go around this if I can't truncate my list.

Comment: This is where you batch it and compile the results in memory.

Comment: We probably need to see the SQL that makes up the `list of 150k emails` as it would appear thats where the issue lies. A possible option might be to split each query within that out such that they insert into a temp table first, then you use your single temp table as your `list of 150k emails`.

Comment: Why not use a join instead?

Comment: First really consider to break up the list into batched. Also, try inserting the email's primary key into a temp table and then joining into that table. 'In' statements really should be limited to about 800 or so items before performance really starts degrading

Comment: thats what I did, batches of 20k emails in my IN statement and its working. But how can I make this simpler... do you need to see my select statement?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use join(s) instead? At least I am assuming your list of emails comes from other tables based on what you are saying.

Comment: why dont you use exists?

Comment: I have just edited my question with my select statements

Comment: Where did you get the 200k emails in the first place, aren't they already in the database?

Comment: They were handed out to me in a csv file .

Comment: My preference would be to insert them into your database in a holding table and JOIN them to your data. Give them a batch ID (something like a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` would work great) to prevent other people interfering with your process.

Comment: No idea how to do this.

Comment: Depending on how often you'll be doing this sort of operation it may be efficient to use [`HashBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to compute a value that can be compared more easily than your secret `email` datatype. (Note that older versions of SQL Server limit the input to 8000 characters.) You may also want to search for articles comparing performance and limitations of [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and `outer join` to `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This many characters can not be processed, that's it. You need to create a csv file and import it with [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You don't need to use a permanent table, you can use a [temp table](https://codingsight.com/introduction-to-temporary-tables-in-sql-server/).

Comment: do you mind showing me an example of how to do this into a temp table?

Comment: It is Method 2 at the second link: prepare a #table and then instead of INSERT INTO you use BULK INSERT.

Comment: It actually works but  I do not have permission which is a different issue. thank you , it will be fixed

Comment: It is normal to use temp tables so all users who have SELECT permission on anything on a SQL server should have permission to use TEMPDB. It is not something extraordinary so you should be granted.